# Accessibility: VoiceOver form control labels with additional text

Tags: html, accessibility

I have a series of "tiles".  Instead of using DIVs, so that keyboard users can select them were are using checkboxes (and sometimes radios as needed).

[image]

the labels for these checkboxes are made of multiple `span` elements for formatting purposes.

the markup is like this:

```
<div class="package-tile-wrapper">
  <input id="parcel-list-item-SFRB" type="checkbox" value="SFRB"> 
  <label class="package-tile" for="parcel-list-item-SFRB">
    <div class="tile-content">
      <span class="package-name">Small Flat Rate Box</span>
      <span class="price">$7.65</span>
      <span>5.375" × 8.625" × 1.625"</span>
      <span>Weight up to 70lb</div>
   </div>
  </label>
</div>
```

The issue I have is that when using VoiceOver (on MacOS Catalina) in Safari it reads the checkbox like this

[image]

I want it to read all the text (price, dimensions, etc.) instead of all the "x more items" stuff.  How can I construct this properly for accessibility?

Comment: What is the functionality meant to be? If I click on an item does a popup appear (I ask as the information in the spans is different to that displayed in the example given). Or do you show a tooltip? Or is it just that the example code shown is for a different item type? Anyway I would imagine the answer is to use `aria-describedby` and point it to multiple IDs but without seeing the full use case that is just a best guess. It works as expected in NVDA on Chrome (reading all `<spans>`) so what screen reader / browser combo is this not working in? You have an extra `<` on line 6 in example btw.

Comment: thanks, the extra < was probably from me stripping down the sample code.  All the info is displayed to users.  I'd like for visually-impaired users to hear the package type, price and dimensions for each as they move between radio buttons.

Comment: I was using VoiceOver on MacOS.  As long as it works for most users it might be ok.

Comment: Just about to eat but I will drop an answer in a bit. Try putting all the spans on one line seperated by spaces as that surprisingly sometimes works. The "proper" way to do it is to use `aria-labelledby` on the `<input>` and point it to the 4 spans in order (each span would need an ID). Harder to maintain so would use a script (frontend or backend) to do this. I will answer later if I can but just wanted to let you know what to do so you could crack on and try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did just test this on VoiceOver on my phone (no Mac to test on :-( ) and it worked as expected. However there are some things you can do / try.

Please note none of the following will get rid of all the "x more items" stuff, that is down to when you use a list or a radio group and is essential information that you want read out.

### Try putting all spans on one line.

As simple as the headings says. Putting all the spans on one line with spaces between them can sometimes fix issues with multiple spans not being read concurrently. You will still get a pause between each span but this isn't a big problem in this case (just something to consider if something is meant to be read as a sentence.)

### Use `aria-labelledby`

I made this suggestion in the comments. If you add an ID to each of the 4 spans you can use `aria-labelledby` on the `<input>` to create the label.

After thinking about I do not think this is the best option due to maintainability but I have included it for reference in case it is useful elsewhere in your project

```
<div class="package-tile-wrapper">
  <input id="parcel-list-item-SFRB" type="checkbox" value="SFRB" aria-labelledby="pack1 price1 size1 weight1"> 
  <label class="package-tile" for="parcel-list-item-SFRB">
    <div class="tile-content">
      <span id="pack1" class="package-name">Small Flat Rate Box</span>
      <span id="price1" class="price">$7.65</span>
      <span id="size1">5.375" × 8.625" × 1.625"</span>
      <span id="weight1">Weight up to 70lb</div>
   </div>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="package-tile-wrapper">
  <input id="parcel-list-item-SFRB" type="checkbox" value="SFRB" aria-labelledby="pack2 price2 size2 weight2"> 
  <label class="package-tile" for="parcel-list-item-SFRB">
    <div class="tile-content">
      <span id="pack2" class="package-name">Medium Flat Rate Box</span>
      <span id="price2" class="price">$9.25</span>
      <span id="size2">6.375" × 9.625" × 2.625"</span>
      <span id="weight2">Weight up to 110lb</div>
   </div>
  </label>
</div>
```

### Build an `aria-label` string either on the server or in JS

One of the issues with the `aria-labelledby` technique (other than maintainability) is that it does not detail what each item is. It would just read the contents of each span one after the other which may be confusing.

Instead I recommend we build a more human-friendly sentence explaining everything. Something along the following lines:

> Small Flat Rate Box, price: $7.65, dimensions: 5.375 inches × 8.625 inches × 1.625 inches, weight: up to 70lb

We would then add this as an `aria-label` on the input.

The beauty of `aria-label` is that it **overrides** any other semantically derived labelling information such as the associated label, giving us complete control over what is being read out.

The approach of using `aria-label` also has the following benefits:

1. It makes it clear what each item being listed is as we have included extra information to describe it
2. If a browser / screen reader combination doesn't support `aria-label` then it would still have some useful information in the `<label>`.
3. It is easier to maintain than a load of IDs and a lot cleaner.

The following is the end result you are looking for, either generated on the server or via JavaScript:

```html
<div class="package-tile-wrapper">
  <input id="parcel-list-item-SFRB" type="checkbox" value="SFRB" aria-label="Small Flat Rate Box, price: $7.65, dimensions: 5.375 inches × 8.625 inches × 1.625 inches, weight: up to 70lb"> 
  <label class="package-tile" for="parcel-list-item-SFRB">
    <div class="tile-content">
      <span class="package-name">Small Flat Rate Box</span>
      <span class="price">$7.65</span>
      <span>5.375" × 8.625" × 1.625"</span>
      <span>Weight up to 70lb</div>
   </div>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="package-tile-wrapper">
  <input id="parcel-list-item-SFRB" type="checkbox" value="SFRB" aria-label="Medium Flat Rate Box, price: $9.25, dimensions: 6.375 inches × 9.625 inches × 3.625 inches, weight: up to 110lb"> 
  <label class="package-tile" for="parcel-list-item-SFRB">
    <div class="tile-content">
       <span class="package-name">Medium Flat Rate Box</span>
       <span class="price">$9.25</span>
       <span>6.375" × 9.625" × 2.625"</span>
       <span>Weight up to 110lb</div>
   </div>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Great solutions.  I will go with the second, as I can easily bind the aria-label with Angular to a function that creates the string.  Thanks.